# How does truffle get the address of the contract only by it's name?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

When executing the command

```
truffle(develop)> let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed()
```

How does truffle get the address of the contract that is deployed ?

Answer (score 2):

The address is stored in the build/contracts/MetaCoin.json file under the `networks` section. Truffle puts the address there when you deploy the contract. You can also manually add addresses to the `networks` section and Truffle with recognize them.